# How can I pull all nested URLs from a webpage using rvest and xml2?

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, rvest

I'm trying to pull all nested links from the webpage below. My code below returns an empty character vector.

```
page1 <- "https://thrivemarket.com/c/condiments-sauces?cur_page=1"
page1 <- read_html(page1)
page1_body <- page1 %>% 
  html_node("body") %>% 
  html_children()

page1_urls <- page1 %>%
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@class, 'd85qmy-0 kRbsKs')]") %>%
  rvest::html_attr('href')
```

Thank you in advance for your help with this.

Best,
~Mayra

Answer (score 0):

The links you are looking for do not exist in the html document you are reading with `read_html`. When you look at the page in a browser, the html document contains Javascript code, which your browser runs. Some of this Javascript code causes your browser to download further information to be inserted into the web page you see on your browser.

In your case, the extra information you are looking for is in the form of a json file, which you can obtain and parse as follows:

```r
library(httr)
library(dplyr)

url <- paste0("https://thrivemarket.com/api/v1/products",
              "?page_size=60&multifilter=1&cur_page=1")

content(GET(url))$products %>%
  lapply(function(x) data.frame(product = x$title, url = x$url)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 60 x 2
#>    product                                          url                         
#>    <chr>                                            <chr>                       
#>  1 Organic Extra Virgin Olive Oil                   https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  2 Grass-Fed Collagen Peptides                      https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  3 Grass-Fed Beef Sticks, Original                  https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  4 Organic Dry Roasted & Salted Cashews             https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  5 Organic Vanilla Extract                          https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  6 Organic Raw Cashews                              https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  7 Organic Coconut Milk, Regular                    https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  8 Organic Robust Maple Syrup, Grade A, Value Size  https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#>  9 Organic Coconut Water                            https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#> 10 Non-GMO Avocado Oil Potato Chips, Himalayan Salt https://thrivemarket.com/p/~
#> # ... with 50 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Allan. I'm not familiar with JSON files, so the only problem is that this code pulls up to 120 items but none listed under the [condiments and sauces category page](https://thrivemarket.com/c/condiments-sauces?cur_page=1). Is there a way to pull all products on the site? Are these separate JSON files?